# MySQL unable to connect with remote server

Tags: mysql, networking, port, windows-server-2008-r2, firewall

We have a MySQL server in one of the remote Virtual Machine (Windows Server 2008). Till yesterday we were able to connect to the MySQL server, with the help of workbench installed in our local machine.

Yesterday there was a restart to the machine which has the Virtual Machine installed. After that we are unable to connect to MYSQL. Though I can ping and remote connect this particular VM. I can even execute the queries inside the workbench installed in the VM.

I am not too good at networking or security related stuffs. Please help me to solve this issue.

Error :

> Your connection attempt failed for user 'root' from your host to server at ABC:3306:  Can't connect to MySQL server on 'ABC' (10060)

Comment: Is the MYSQL Service running? Are there any erros in the logs (Event Viewer)?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Really this could be a magnitude of possible reasons, hopefully this is a start:

**Check basic network**

From the MySQL virtual machine open up a command prompt and type `IPCONFIG /ALL`. This will show you all the IP addresses bound to different network adapters.

Check that the IP address you're connected to is listed there, the virtual machine might have got a new IP from DHCP rather than having a static IP after its restart.

**Hostname vs IP**

You should check the hostname resolution, from your quoted error it would suggest you are you are connecting to a hostname rather than a server IP.  Check your machine can resolve to the hostname using the correct IP address - it could also be worth changing the hostname for the actual IP of the server in the connection string.

**MySQL config file**

You've said you're running MySQL on Windows, it was customary to rename the `my.cnf` to `my.ini`.  The configuration file for older versions of MySQL previous to 4.1.5 was usually stored in either `c:\my.ini` or `c:\windows\my.ini`.  For versions after this the default location is the installation directory usually `%PROGRAMDATA%\MySQL\MySQL Server xxx`.

When you have located the configuration file please open it on Notepad (or similar text editor), locate the `[mysqld]` section and make sure that `port=` the port you're trying to connect to and `bind-address=` the IP address you're trying to connect to.

**Server ports**

From the MySQL virtual server open a command prompt and type `netstat –ano`, this will show you a list of processes and what IP's / ports they are listening on.  The MySQL server should be listed here and should be listening on the same port and IP as the config file defines.

**Windows firewall**

You should have a firewall rule to allow MySQL, the following will add one on the default port of 3306

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="MySQL Server" action=allow protocol=TCP dir=in localport=3306
```

**Identify if this is machine specific**

You could setup the MySQL Workbench application on another workstation and try to connect to identify if this is a global problem or just one related to your specific workstation.

Comment: @TBA 4 days radio silence - did you manage to solve your problem?

Comment: Indeed it got solved :) And sorry for the late reply. port= had a different port. Thanks it got solved.

Answer (score 11):

mysql administrator of your database should allow remote connection to the mysql server.
change this in my.cnf:

```
bind-address    = 127.0.0.1 # this should be your mysql server ip
```

and comment this:

```
# skip-networking
```

Comment: Dear Volkan, where can I find this my.cnf

Comment: If you are using Debian Linux file is located at /etc/mysql/my.cnf location.
If you are using Red Hat Linux/Fedora/Centos Linux file is located at /etc/my.cnf location.
If you are using FreeBSD you need to create a file /var/db/mysql/my.cnf location.

Comment: I am using Windows Server 2008 R2

Comment: this might not be a mysql issue then. i don't know how windows handles remote connections but this looks like a networking issue. check this one out, if this doesn't work then its definitely networking issue. http://www.programcreek.com/2009/09/how-to-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-server-on-windows/

Comment: and also set the bind address to 0.0.0.0. This will ensure that your mysql accept connection on all available interfaces rather than just one. Then find on which port your mysql server is listenning on (default is 3306) and ensure the host machine does not block it. The real solution may also depend on what virtualisation you are using what are its security settings and you have not specified them.

Comment: Dear Akilesh , thanks for the heads up. I will let you know the VM specification. However this was working till the hosting server upgraded to increase the licence after that we restarted the host machine, then on wards the MYSQl is unable to connect via remote connection.

Answer (score 8):

Chances are that your configuration was set up for an IP that has changed. By default, mysql won't let you connect from remote hosts unless you explicitly give permissions for a specific user on a specific schema or a group of schemas, for example if you did something like this:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'USERNAME'@'1.2.3.4' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Maybe what you actually did was to set the grant onto your own IP address, that is the address of your local machine, and if your local machine (not the remote server) has changed it's IP address, then mysql will not let you connect unless you have the "1.2.3.4" IP address which obviously you don't have anymore if you have a dynamic IP address (common with DSL/Cable connections)

So connect through SSH or Telnet or whatever you use to your windows server and go to mysql as root and do this:

```
SELECT * from information_schema.user_privileges;
```

That will show you the grants on all users and how they are allowed to connect. If you don't see your local IP Address listed there or a wildcard (which would allow you to connect from any remote machine to the server) then you have to set it up like this:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'USERNAME'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Where USERNAME of course is your user. See that after the on there is a wildcard / dot /wildcard that means you want that user to be able to connect to any schema (database, for mysql) from any user from any network. But I'd recommend that you only do the grant for the user for the specific schema you need to connect to.

Then after that, if you actually had the right information and still can't connect than use a portscanner like [nmap](http://nmap.org/zenmap/) or something like that to do a port scan and see if mysql is:

1. Open and listening to external network
2. Running on the port that you actually want to connect through

If 1 is true, then check 2 because maybe there is a misconfiguration of the port. But if any of these 2 points do work then it sounds definitely not like a network configuration but a user setting or something else.

Answer (score 2):

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* to user@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

this command should do the trick for all users @Gustavo Rubio has already given the proper explanation.

To ensure what ports are open run cmd in the virtual machine and type.

```
netstat -a

TCP    127.0.0.1:3360     Hostname:3360   LISTENING
```

The my.cnf is located  Mysql-install-path\MySQL\MySQL Server xxx make sure you backup original before changing

[Can't connect to [local] MySQL server](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html)

[Testing The MySQL Server Installation on Microsoft Windows](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-windows-excerpt/5.1/en/windows-testing.html)

[MySQL Workbench: Manage MySQL on Windows Servers the Windows way](http://mysqlworkbench.org/2010/12/mysql-workbench-manage-mysql-on-windows-servers-the-windows-way/)

Answer (score 0):

For the first time you need to test and make sure your connection to mysql is not blocked by the firewall.

To disable the firewall on each host in your cluster, perform the following steps on each host.

**1. Save the existing iptables rule set.**

```
iptables-save > /root/firewall.rules
```

**2. Disable iptables.**

For RHEL, CentOS, Oracle, and Debian:

```
chkconfig iptables off
```

and

```
/etc/init.d/iptables stop
```

For SLES:

```
chkconfig SuSEfirewall2_setup off
```

and

```
rcSuSEfirewall2 stop
```

For Ubuntu:

```
service ufw stop
```

https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-7-x/topics/install_cdh_disable_iptables.html

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your setup, but if you're using cPanel just go to RemoteMYSQL and enter your host. You can also use a wildcard. Below worked for me when I was getting the error

> "Could not connect to DB server '' as user ''. port : Host '' is not
>   allowed to connect to this MySQL server"

[image: cPanel setup to allow remote mysql connection]

Answer (score 0):

On MySQL v5.6 this may be the case.
When another server communicate by advertising its hostname instead of IP address, the resolution might fails (because your user is using IP address instead of hostname for example).

So, you need to **disable** the following,

```
skip-host-cache
skip-name-resolve
```

Or maybe create the user with appropriate hostname (instead of IP address). You may find the hostname when establishing the connection to the remote MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

as root temporarily disable the firewall:

```
systemctl stop firewalld
systemctl is-enabled firewalld
```

also see the output (the status of your network device.):

```
nmcli dev status
```