# ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on xx.xx.xx.xx

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, remote-access, remote-server

I tried to connect mySQL from remote server I followed these commands:
convert

```
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

to

```
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

and followed by,

```
systemctl restart mysql.service
```

then login to mySQL server in local machine and gave following command:

```
GRANT ALL ON databaseName.* TO 'user'@'xx.xx.xx.xx' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

then tried in remote server with following command:

```
mysql -u user -p -h xx.xx.xx.xx
```

Got error as:

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'xx.xx.xx.xx'
```

Can someone help on this? How can I connect mySQL remotely?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL unable to connect with remote server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21627421/mysql-unable-to-connect-with-remote-server)

Comment: Did you check firewall?

Comment: @songoku1610 No, I did not,

Comment: Check your firewall or network first, maybe the firewall blocked your connection

Comment: @songoku1610 I checked, it is inactive.